# Schema-based multitenancy: getting "java.sql.SQLException: No database selected" from time to time

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc

My code written in Java, and I using Spring JDBC Template for accessing MySQL database.

My system is a multi-tenant and each tenant has its own dedicated schema in MySQL (e.g. "tenant_1", "tenant_2", etc).

This is how database connection being initialized:

During bootstrap, I creating a bean exposing [DataSourceTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.html), which is initialized by DataSource configured with a connection string of the MySQL database (without specifying schema).

Since my system is multi-tenant, for each request I have to select schema of the given tenant. Therefore, typical query looks like this:

1. "USE tenant_xxx"
2. ....

The problem:

From time to time (1 to thousands of executions), I am getting

> java.sql.SQLException: No database selected.

I double checked my code - indeed, I do always selecting schema before query execution.

Any ideas?

- Spring - latest version (5.x)
- Java - 11
- MySQL (5.7), reproduced both on local MySQL and AWS Aurora

UPDATE: adding more info

- I using Spring Boot, which by default using HikariCP
- I notice that issue in random places in code, so most likely it is not a bug in specific place in *my code*

UPDATE 2:

- Connector/J version 8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have configuration stuff for the connection pooling, please provide it.

Sounds like the connection pooling is switching connections between the `USE` and the subsequent DDL/DML statement.

Also, is there a way to assign a database to a pool entry or vice versa?

Comment: This is our current working theory as well. We doing refactoring in code and soon we will see. About pool configuration - there is none - we just using default Spring Boot configuration

Comment: Another thought...  If you (or Spring) fails to check for errors, there could be a `USE` statement that, instead of setting the database, acts as a 'ping' to auto-reconnect.  Auto-reconnect is not a good idea because it can mess up transactions.

Answer (score 4):

There are many things that can go wrong, I'll try to provide general thoughts hopefully some of them will be useful.

So, given the information:

1. General thought. Try to log the sql requests so that when the error happens you'll see whether its always the same request / type of request (something that leads to bug in some specific area of the code) or not.
2. Check your connection pool. You haven't specified the actual pool, but its clear from the question that its not a "self-education" project or something, so you might have one.
   Sometimes they have bugs when trying to handle the multi-tenant environment.
3. Check the approach of adding the schema name in the query if its applicable, maybe there is a bug in the driver or something (not likely). I mean, instead of

```
USE XYZ
select * from foo
```

you could use

```
select from xyz.foo
```

Comment: Hi Mark, 

I edited question to provide more info. Basically we using HikariCP, definitely they might have a bug in multi-tenant environment (I will try to ask them). Also, we saw this issue happens in multiple places, so most likely it is not a bug in our code (at least not on query level)

תודה

Comment: Cool. One more general thought in this case. Any chance to switch Hikari CP to some other pool just to check whether the issue still exists? The change should be transparent (Configuration properties + dependency)...

Comment: About using "fully qualified" table names (e.g. schema.table): this is not a scalable approach, since Connector/J parsing and caching each SQL as a "precompiled" statement. This cache is a dictionary where key is an original SQL statement (string). Therefore, using fully qualified table name will make duplicate caches of all used SQL statements as a number of schemas.

Comment: Btw  can you post a small code snippet that shows how exactly you use the jdbc template, maybe you just do it in a wrong way that usually works, but sometimes fails...

Comment: I thought about scenario where the “use” statement is executed on one connection but then the actual statement is executed on another in case of error. Usually this doesn’t happen because the same connection is picked from the pool but sometimes (multithreading high load who knows) the pool offers a different connection for actual sql statement ... seeing some actual code could help to provide a solution or maybe suggest how to check that

Comment: @Illidan - Do you have a link to the page describing that "precompilation"?

Comment: @RickJames: One source for example: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration. But you can look yourself in code (my-sql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar), ConnectionImpl class, method "createPreparedStatementCaches()"